# I'm going to update some collections in a function

Tags: scala

#### I'm going to put some collections into a function as parameters, and update these collections

> See the comment lins, here will be a error: Reassignment to val. How I can solve this, seems the function parameters are Value, not Variable

```
get("/email/:number/summary") {
    ...
    var lobs = List[String]()
    var pagesOfLob = Map[String, List[String]]()
    var summariesByPosOfLob = Map[String, List[(String, List[Map[String, String]])]]()

    wrapEmailRportData(lobs, pagesOfLob, summariesByPosOfLob)

    ssp(...)
}

def wrapEmailRportData(jsonString: String, lobs: List[String], 
    pagesOfLob: Map[String, List[String]], summariesByPosOfLob: Map[String, List[(String, List[Map[String, String]])]]) : Unit = {
    val summaries = convertJsonToObject(jsonString)
    groupBy("lob", summaries, List("homepage"))
        .foreach(group => {
            val summariesOfLob = summaries.filter(_("lob") == "homepage") ::: group._2
            val uniquePagesOfLob = getUniqueValues(summariesOfLob, "page")
            lobs = lobs :+ group._1 // error: Reassignment to "val"
            pagesOfLob += (group._1 -> uniquePagesOfLob) // error: Reassignment to "val"
            summariesByPosOfLob += (group._1 -> groupBy("pos", summariesOfLob, List())) // error: Reassignment to "val"
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm going to put some collections into a function as parameters, and update these collections

That's a really bad idea.

When learning Scala, and Functional Programming in general, students should avoid bad habits like mutable data, functions that return `Unit`, `foreach()` loops, and other constructs that rely on side effects.

So instead of passing in mutable collections to be filled (which can't be done), the method should build and populate the collections internally and return them as a 3-element tuple (aka a "triple").

The method signature might look like this.

```
def wrapEmailRportData(jsonString :String) :(List[String]
                                            ,Map[String,List[String]]
                                            ,Map[String,List[(String,List[Map[String,String]])]]
                                            ) = { . . .
```

And you might invoke it like this.

```
val (lobs, pagesOfLob, summariesByPosOfLob) = wrapEmailRportData(jsonStr)
```

As for the method body, I'm sure the return elements can all be built without using mutable collections. Start by studying `foldLeft` and develop an understanding of how it works.

Comment: You are right, thanks much for your professional answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The function parameters are treated as `val`s and thus don't support reassignment. There is no support for `var` parameters.

What you could do is create `var` containers, and then copy the elements from `lobs` and `pagesOfLobs` into those containers. Then, you can reassign as you wish. Thing is you can't update the collection you passed in, so you'd have to return a result.

For example:

```
def doSomething(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  var result = xs
  for (i <- 1 to 5) {
    result = result :+ i // Create new list on every iteration
  }
  return result
}

println(doSomething(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
// List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

There are much better, idiomatic approaches, but this is if you wish to keep your imperative-looking approach.